# How can I load a javascript file with document.write inside of createElement?

Tags: javascript

Is there some way to load a js file that got document.write inside?

i.e:

```
(function(){

    var test = document.createElement('script');
    test.type="text/javascript";
    test.src="http://xxxxxxxxxxx/test.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(test);

})();
```

**test.js:**

```
document.write('test !');
```

it always returns alert error about document.write async ...

I figured out if i do:

**test.js:**

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = 'test !';
```

it works !

but in my case i can't have access to js file, then i would like to know if is there a way to do it? or i'll need to do a cross with php curl.

thanks.

Comment: You could try to overwrite the document.write function before loading the script.

Answer (score 3):

`document.write()` is designed for use while the document is being parsed.  If you use it from a dynamically loaded script after the document has been loaded, then it will clear the current document and start writing a brand new document.

If you want to add content to the current document from a dynamically loaded script, then you should use DOM manipulation functions like `document.createElement()` and `.appendChild()` or `.insertBefore()`, not `document.write()`.

Comment: +1 – and to add further to that, the OP should read what HTML5 says about [document.write](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dynamic-markup-insertion.html#document.write), noting that it is not standardised and still very much implementation dependent (HTML5 essentially documents existing behaviour). However I think it goes a bit overboard with the warnings, *document.write* is very useful when used appropriately.